# Finding missing elements in arrays

Tags: java

My program is  : In an array 1-10 numbers are stored, one number is missing how do you find it?

I have tried the following code, but it is not giving the right output.

```
public class MissingNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10 };
        System.out.println(arr.length);

        int arr2[] = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {

            arr2[i] = i + 1;
            System.out.println("second array is : " + arr2[i]);
        }

        //compare two arrays i.e arr and arr2

        for(int a=0;a<arr.length;a++){
            for(int b=0;b<arr2.length;b++){
                 if(arr[a]==arr2[b]){
                     break;
                 }
                 else{
                     System.out.println("missing element is : "+arr[a]);
                 }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

I want the number which is missing. Can anyone please let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: why not just: if ( arr[a] != (a+1)) ?

Comment: Its working. Thanks !

Comment: @naazneen3264 The question isn't clear, you might not even need a single loop to find the "missing" number. Is you array always starting from 1 and supposed to be in increasing order?

Comment: yeah..I realised later .

Answer (score 1):

Check below code for if input array is any order or shuffled maner

public class MissingNumber {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 10};
    System.out.println(arr.length);

    int arr2[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        arr2[i] = i + 1;
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < arr2.length; a++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int b = 0; b < arr.length; b++) {
            if (arr2[a] == arr[b]) {
                break;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (arr2.length == count) {
            System.out.println("missing element is : " + arr2[a]);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking out from the loop once there is a match from the 2 arrays. From the point of your logic, change it to (you don't need nested loops):

```
if(arr[a]!=arr2[a]){
    System.out.println("missing element is : "+arr[a]);
    break;
}
```

But if it is certain that the array is always in sequential order from 1 onwards, you don't need another array. Just do it as:

```
for(int x=0; x<arr.lengthl x++){
    if(arr[x] != (x+1)){
        System.out.println("Missing element is " + (x+1));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working. But the second part is working. Actually I took 2 arrays and tried to find the missing element.

Answer (score 0):

You just broke the code when u found a correct match:

Just use the following:

```
if(arr[a] != arr2[b]){
    System.out.println("missing element is : "+arr[a]);
    break;
}
```

Or just replace break with continue

Comment: Caspar: in which situation do you think this print line will ever be reached?

Comment: Yeah i realized that a second after i wrote it :p

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second array, you don't need it and it might just lead to errors once you add elements to the original array.

Basically, replace your test by:

```
if(arr[a] != (a+1)){ System.out.println("Missing element: " + (a+1)); }
```

Don't break out of it, since there might be more elements missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you are looping through `arr` looking for any value that is not in `arr2`, and every element in `arr` IS in `arr2`. You want `arr2` as the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

> My program is : In an array 1-10 numbers are stored, one number is missing how do you find it?

It can also be done using just the array itself. Please note that it only works if one of the numbers is missing as specified in this question.

For Example,

Let Array be `array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,9,10}`.

Now, let us assume that Array will not always be sorted and hence the first step is to sort the array.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Next step is to simply check the array's value at any given location, if the `value != location + 1` then that is the missing number.

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    if(array[x] != x + 1) {
        System.out.println("Missing Entry: " + (x+1));
        break;
    }
}
```